# When Activity is displayed as Dialog then Web View is not displaying local image loaded from SD Card.

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new to Android and in my project I got a requirement to display image preview in Web View, whenever user clicks preview Button. I acheived the same using the method `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, but now I need to display that Activity as Dialog, it failed to display the image. I have overridden the `onResume()` method also, but I am unable to display image.

Thanks in Advance